# How to map a Windows path for remote server correctly in git?

Tags: git

Host: Ubuntu 20.04 (with Virtualbox) with openssh & git, smoothly running .

Guest OS(virtual machine): Win7 under Virtualbox (NAT network), with openssh (sshd) & git installed. I've a project in Win7 C:\users\administrator\path\to\project

Goal: I want to write codes for this project in host Ubuntu and then push codes to virtual Win7.

I could not manage set-up of smart HTTP for serving GIT in Win7, and SSH is more recommended. So I'm trying SSH.
In Virtualbox, NAT network means no direct access from host to guest. One workaround is port-forwarding. Now in Ubuntu I can access Win7 by "ssh -p 2222 127.0.0.1" with no problem. However, "git pull ssh://administrator@127.0.0.1:2222/path/to/project" fails with "fatal: ''/path/to/project'' does not appear to be a git repository".

I tried to put the "/path/to/project", after 127.0.0.1:2222, as "C:/users/administrator/path/to/project" and others, but none worked. How shall I put this "path/to/project" in this "git pull..." command?

Comment: so you run ```git pull ssh://administrator@127.0.0.1:2222/C:/user/administrator/path/to/project``` ?

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, "ssh://administrator@127.0.0.1:2222/C:/users/administrator/path/to/project" did not work. Neither did "ssh://administrator@127.0.0.1:2222/C/users/administrator/path/to/project", nor "ssh://[administrator@127.0.0.1:2222]/C/users/administrator/path/to/project ....

Comment: The details depend on the ssh server, but when I ssh into a Linux box as myself, for instance, with `ssh://me@linux.box.name/path/to/repo.git`, all *relative* paths from there are relative to my home directory. Whether `C:` works here at all, and if so how, is going to depend on your ssh server. You're likely to have better luck working with a path relative to the login home directory (although again this depends on the server). One way to figure out what's going on is to run `ssh user@addr:2222 ls` (or `dir` or `pwd` or something that helps figure out where you are).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround:
Change the default shell of openssh to bash. It works now. But, I do not think this is the best solution.

run this line of command under powershell:
`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force`